# jQuery - Is it okay to use $('#ElementId') everytime?

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

I just learned how to do the 'document.getElementById' counterpart in jQuery (and it's more powerful). My question is, is it okay to use it everytime or every line of code? Here's how I use it now:

```
$('#MyParentElement').html('<tr id="' + $('#MyElement').val() + '"><td>' + $('#MyElement').val() + '</td></tr>';
```

Isn't better if I do something like using a variable to reference the object?

```
var x = $('#MyElement');
$('#MyParentElement').html('<tr id="' + x.text() + '"><td>' + x.text() + '</td></tr>';
```

Note that I'm more concern of the performance, not the cleanliness of the codes.

Comment: short answer, yes.  because $() is actually a function call and as with JavaScript in general, if you see yourself calling the same function with the same arguments numerous times, just store it in a variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DOM selection is expensive. Cache it.

```
var x = $('#MyElement');
```

---

[Here's a jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/dom-select-vs-caching). In Chrome 13 on Mac OS X, the variable reference is over 1,000 times faster.

This is not only due to the DOM selection of course, but also the construction of the jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks! You really have helped me! :)

Comment: You should qualify that, however.  Variable reference is 1,000 times faster in a synthetic benchmark that references the same element thousands of times.  In real code you would never do such a thing, and the actual performance benefit would be closer to `r - 1` times faster, where `r` is the number of references to the element.  In terms of what the user experiences, there is probably no perceptible difference between either approach, unless you are doing hundreds of consecutive references to the element.

Comment: @aroth - I want to consider every line of my codes to make the web faster.

Comment: @aroth: *"there is probably no perceptible difference between either approach"* OK, so? Good coding practices are good coding practices. There's still a massive performance difference between the two. That should be no surprise. There's no compelling reason as far as I can tell to not use the optimized code. It would be silly to adopt a practice of unnecessarily repeating DOM selections just because in a particular instance the user may not notice the difference.

Comment: @domanokz: That's good. It all adds up in the end. If you maintain a mindset of writing performant code, it will make a noticable difference at some point.

Comment: @patrick - So nothing.  I'm just making a point about the accuracy of the benchmark and the "1,000 times faster" claim.  I don't dispute that it's faster or better.  But that doesn't mean that I want people thinking that by replacing 3 DOM queries with 3 variable references their code will speed up by a factor of 1,000 or more.

Answer (score 2):

Yes will be better, for performance and coding style.

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/caching-in-jquery.html

[jQuery / javascript caching elements for efficiency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011403/jquery-javascript-caching-elements-for-efficiency)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the second code only queries the DOM once for `x`, yes, it is a much better idea to store the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

why not?

```
var x = $('#MyElement').text();
$('#MyParentElement').html('<tr id="' + x + '"><td>' + x + '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: My point is, is it better to select object overtime or to create a reference variable. Thanks anyway for pointing it out!

Comment: I'll use your code only if I will only be needing the value of the element... Thanks again!

Comment: yeah, but to answer your question - instead of calling x.text() 2 times it only has to call it once. Of course it's better.

Answer (score 1):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but it's my understanding that if you used the second option (ie var x = $('#myElement')) that it wouldn't update dynamically. If #myElement changed, as elements sometimes do, you'd still be referencing whatever it was when you assigned its value to X.

If you don't feel like #myElement is going to change, then go ahead and use the var x option. As others have said, it's a bit quicker.

Comment: Yes, I'm certain that the element would not change. Thanks for reply!

Comment: I'm not cloning the object, I'm creating a variable as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Storing $('#MyParentElement') in a variable would be faster, however by a small margin since selection by element ID is fast. Though if building a large JS app then it could add up.

Comment: I'm not cloning the object, I'm creating a variable as reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's about as okay as calling `document.getElementById` every time would be.

Technically it is better to go with your second option, and store the result to a variable if you will be accessing it repeatedly.  But in practical terms, unless you have hundreds of references to the same element then the difference is not going to be noticeable to the user.