# How to use a reference variable in a jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I learned that using a reference variable is faster than using `$()` every line of code (see my previous question): [jQuery - Is it okay to use $('#ElementId') everytime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542646/jquery-is-it-okay-to-use-elementid-everytime). Now my question is how can I use this reference variable to maximize the power of jQuery? Please see the example below:

Without reference variable:

```
var ValueOfSelected = $('#SelectElementId option:selected').val();
```

With reference variable (pseudo-code):

```
var SelectElement = $('#SelectElementId');
var ValueOfSelected = $(SelectElement).SelectedOption.val();
```

Note that `SelectedOption.val()` is the pseudo-code here. Is there such function anyway?

Comment: You don't need to do `$(SelectElement)` again, you can just use `SelectElement` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.find()` to find the nested `option`.

```
var SelectElement = $('#SelectElementId');
var ValueOfSelected = SelectElement.find('option:selected').val();
```

...but because it is a `select` element, you can just use the [`val()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method directly.

```
var SelectElement = $('#SelectElementId');
var ValueOfSelected = SelectElement.val();
```

This will give you the value of the selected `option`.

Comment: Ha ha! It's you again! Hey, This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var select_element = $('#SelectElementId');
// these two below gives you the same result
var value_of_selected = $('#SelectElementId option:selected').val();
var value_of_selected = select_element.val();
```

sometimes you don't really have to use reference variables. it's useful if you actually use it multiple times.

Comment: You mean, I cannot use my reference variable in jQuery? This time I really need to use a reference variable 'coz I'll be using  it for many times.

Comment: i've edited my post to show how you can also use the reference variable.

Answer (score 1):

The result of a JQuery selector, in this case "SelectElement" can be accessed through out the rest of the script.  You dont need to use the JQuery Selector "$()" a second time.